# what is the meaning of this es script of [INCREASE](a,b) { }

Tags: ecmascript-6

I want to know what is the meaning of `[INCREASE](state, data){ }` from this grammar:

```
import INCREASE from ...

const mutations = {
  [INCREASE](state, data){
    state.points = data
  }
}
```

thanks a lot !

Comment: What does "complete" mean in this context? It would help if you could make it clearer what your question is.

Comment: thanks @loganfsmyth , I updated my question.